# Which api is good for android and what are different types?

Tags: android, android-json, android-webservice

I have heard about json and xml (SOAP) services , in fact there are SOAP and restful services and we can get reply in json format and xml format. now let me tell you what My real question is but after a little background of the story.

I am using a web service which return me the following respone

```
 <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"OSID":"2","PhoneVersion":"IPHONE5","PhoneOS":"IOS","ImageName":"t_6@2x.png","ImageID":"6"},{"OSID":"2","PhoneVersion":"IPHONE5","PhoneOS":"IOS","ImageName":"t_7@2x.png","ImageID":"7"},{"OSID":"2","PhoneVersion":"IPHONE5","PhoneOS":"IOS","ImageName":"t_8@2x.png","ImageID":"8"},{"OSID":"2","PhoneVersion":"IPHONE5","PhoneOS":"IOS","ImageName":"t_9@2x.png","ImageID":"9"},{"OSID":"2","PhoneVersion":"IPHONE5","PhoneOS":"IOS","ImageName":"t_10@2x.png","ImageID":"10"},{"OSID":"2","PhoneVersion":"IPHONE5","PhoneOS":"IOS","ImageName":"t_11@2x.png","ImageID":"11"},{"OSID":"2","PhoneVersion":"IPHONE5","PhoneOS":"IOS","ImageName":"t_12@2x.png","ImageID":"12"}]
</string>
```

Now I do not know what is this format and I really do not know which services is this though it is made by my friend.

So I have couple of question along with the post Title question

1. What type of response is this ?
2. How many type of response are there for mobile development and which is fast and efficient specially when we are getting also image in return.
3. Do restful services can also send response in xml or other format or json response ensure that services is restful.

Now My final Question and may be most importantly

1. > How to parse this type of response and to save it in local class
   >   variable like Static string Image name etc etc

Please answer me and remove my confusion about restful services and soup services and answer the question I asked above. Thanks

Comment: When you say Soup, you mean SOAP I guess..

Comment: yeah sorry type mistake unintentioanly

Comment: do you know what type of reply is this

Comment: @Oscar what do you mean ? please explain

Comment: application/json is the mime type of the response.

Comment: so how to parse this , please give me an example

Comment: Too broad, go and read some articles in internet and come back with specifics questions

Comment: @Oscar this is my specific question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547428/how-to-parse-the-xml-wrapping-json?noredirect=1#comment54874650_33547428

Answer (score 1):

1. JSON data with an XML wrapper
2. Infinite! You can always make your own type. JSON is very popular
3. REST doesn't prescribe a specific message format. XML or JSON is fine as the message format.

And

1. Use one of the many parsers available to you (they are quite good)

Comment: great , can you please tell how can I parse that specific result